# Apache 403 forbidden when visiting website

Tags: vagrant

I'm running Vagrant and Virtualbox on my macOS Catalina. Installed latest versions of both software and I created a vagrant file with [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) and used Apache as webserver. Ran `vagrant up` and all fine.

I've added a vhost like I allways do and have running on a different Mac (with macOS Mojave).
However, if I access the website on de virtual machine, I get a 403, access forbidden.

The default host that is setup, with html, seems to run fine. But this is not running php, only html.

My vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.test

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain

  ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/html

  <Directory "/var/www/domain/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
      Require all granted
      SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
    </FilesMatch>

  </Directory>

  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_access.log" combined

  ## Custom fragment

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try after enabling php mods, for my php5 project, I have used:

```
a2enmod php5
a2enmod headers
a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: I added the mods, but no succes. Also, php7.2 mod is not available on my machine.

Comment: mod are required to run php files. btw try to see, access.log of your host machine, whether it is getting hit or not.